# Version Control for lots of static websites

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github, process

We are a small team of 5-6 people who are constantly going into our websites and doing regular maintenance and updates.  We have over 300+ websites that we deal with.

We just added a new team member who will start tomorrow and we are looking to update our processes and start using Version Control before things start to get out of hand.

Right now, we just are working live and making the changes through FTP.  So if two people have the same file open, one could get overwritten and it could end bad.  It's just a disaster waiting to happen, so I would like to fix it before it gets worse.

---

Ideally, we would like to use some sort of Version Control System where we could:

- Not worry about overwriting someones changes
- Ability to convert back to a certain revision if something goes wrong
- Ability for team members to describe the changes they are making
- Have a testing place where we could commit the changes and test it on another server, and once that looks good, we can publish it to the live website.

I have looked at **github** and **Beanstalk** and I have a few questions:

- If we have 300+ websites, can all of those be under **one** repository?  Or would I need a separate one fore each?  Not sure how that would work.
- Which Version Control System would you recommend?

---

I would really like to get an idea of what other companies are using and how the whole process works when you have a few team members working on the same sites.

The sites are static information websites, with no more than 30 pages so they are small websites, and the changes aren't anything too crazy just adding/editing content or adding some buttons, just basic changes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend BitBucket, which is hosted by Atlassian. 
https://bitbucket.org/plans

If you only need 5 users, you can actually get it for free.

All plans include an unlimited amount of private repositories; unlimited disk space, wiki etc.

However, if your team ever expands, it may start to get a little pricey. Since pricing is user based.

In terms of how you would organize all this. It may be a good idea to have a seperate repository for each, so there is no confusion to where the code for a certain web page may be.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wise decision to start using a version control system to manage your websites.

Most of the version control tools can fulfill your requirements: getting better cooperation, tracking histories, and etc.

> If we have 300+ websites, can all of those be under one repository? Or
>   would I need a separate one fore each? Not sure how that would work.

It depends. If these 300+ websites are related (for instance, some parts are shared among the websites), it's recommended to put them under one repository. Otherwise, either will be OK.

> Which Version Control System would you recommend?

Since these are small websites, I recommend you use a hosting service. github is a good option. You can also consider SourceAnywhere Hosted.